# How do choose picture from gallery and save as background ImageView, using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview

I'm new to Android programming. I would like to know how to choose a image from gallery and put it as the ImageView background.
I made the code to choose from gallery and make it the ImageView background, but the image disappears every time I leave the application.
I must be saved in the database, but i dont have much knowledge about it

If someone can help me ..
Thank you

My Java file

```
    ImageView btn1, btn2;
    Uri photoPath;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Altere o botão"), 1);
            }
        });

}

    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){

        if(resCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(reqCode == 1){
                btn1.setImageURI(data.getData());
            }
        }
    }
```

My XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.camera.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use convert your image into Bytes and then using sqlLite database connectivity you can store and retrieve your image form database.
For this Please refer to this example: 
[Example to store images in SQLLite database in android](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Looks like your code for fetching an image and setting it to the Imageview is working fine.
My suggestion is save the image in a local folder and not in the Sqlite database as it makes the database heavy. But do save the Uri or path of the image in the database.

Use the below code to save the image in a local folder

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This is an easy Tutorial for Sqlite Database [Sqlite Database tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)